# Silverlight: Set MaxWidth of a textblock to containing column width

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

in my Silverlight 4 App, I have a simple 3-columns Grid, that contains 3 Textblocks.

```
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource BrushCharacteristicListBoxItemBackground}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCharacteristicName" Text="{Binding Property1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Text}" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSeperator" Text="=" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCharacteristicValue" Text="{Binding Property3}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,0" />
        </Grid>
```

The width of the Grid depends on the containing user control. Now I want to cap the size of the first and the third textblock to the current size of their containing column, probably using MaxSize and bind it somehow to the size of the Column of the Grid.

Can anyone here tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

By default the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `TextBlock` is set to "Stretch" so it will fill the available size of the column its in, regardless of its content.  Is that what you want?

Perhaps for some reason you do not want the `TextBlock` to be as wide as the Column it is in if its content does not need all the available space?

If so set the `TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment` to "Left".  The `TextBlock` will then be only as wide as it needs to be *until* it reaches the width of the column, then its width will be constrained by the column.

Comment: This is what i thought too and actually the HorizontalAlignement of my TextBlock (TextBlockCharacteristicName) is set to left. Still, the size of the TextBlock is NOT constrained by the width of the column, but pushes the width of the column to fit the size of the textblock

Comment: @Aaginor:  My guess is that you are presenting these grids in a ListBox.  For the * sizing to make sense the containing element that the Grid is placed in must constrain the size of its content.  The ListBox internally places the content in a ScrollViewer which by definition doesn't place any constraints on the width and height of the content.

Comment: Uhm, you are guessing right! I didn't thought that that matters. So, is there any chance to achieve the constraining of the size in that case? I thought about setting the MaxWidth to something like {Binding Grid.Column[0].ActualWidth}, but didn't find any working solution.